# Java 16 ChromeDriver WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type even after following all the necessary steps

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Eclipse version:2021-09
Java version:16.0.2
selenium version:selenium-java-3.141.59
Chromedriver version: compatible to 94.0.4606.71
Changed the compiler compliance level to 1.8
Added jar files to the class path of Libraries

Yet why am I getting this error?
I have attached an image above.

Comment: See [ask] - check formatting question before posting. And where's the image you attached?

Answer (score 1):

Deleted `module-info.java` file. It worked.