# error org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpInfo: module org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver does not declare `uses`

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, javafx, selenium-remotedriver

I wanted to create a JavaFX application that uses Selenium for web scraping, but it didn't go well.

I can't find how to solve this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpInfo: module
org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver does not declare `uses`
```

(Full project: https://github.com/Ege-BULUT/BrokenApp)

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ege</groupId>
    <artifactId>instagramtool</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>instagramtool</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>
                    <target>15</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.ege.instagramtool/com.ege.instagramtool.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**HelloApplication.java**

```
package com.ege.instagramtool;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 600, 400);
        stage.setTitle("Hi stalker!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.ege.instagramtool;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class HelloController {

    private String username = "", password = "", url = "";
    private WebDriver browser;

    @FXML
    private TextField in_username, in_password, in_url;
    @FXML
    private Button btn_insta, btn_search;
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    void onInstaBtnClick(ActionEvent event) {
        browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/");
    }

    @FXML
    void onSearchBtnClick(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:/PROJELER/WebScraping/ChromeDrivers/chromedriver_102.exe");
        browser = new ChromeDriver();

        in_url.setDisable(true);
        btn_insta.setDisable(true);
        btn_search.setDisable(true);

        in_username.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldText, newText)->{
            if(in_username.getText().length()>0){
                username = in_username.getText();
                if(!password.isBlank()){
                    btn_insta.setDisable(false);
                }
            }else{
                username = "";
                btn_insta.setDisable(true);
            }
        });

        in_password.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldText, newText)->{
            if(in_password.getText().length()>0){
                password = in_password.getText();
                if(!username.isBlank()){
                    btn_insta.setDisable(false);
                }
            }else{
                password = "";
                btn_insta.setDisable(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbcHr.png)

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program
Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=55468:C:\Program
Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\15.0.1\javafx-controls-15.0.1.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\15.0.1\javafx-graphics-15.0.1.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\15.0.1\javafx-base-15.0.1.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\15.0.1\javafx-fxml-15.0.1.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\service\auto-service-annotations\1.0.1\auto-service-annotations-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\service\auto-service\1.0.1\auto-service-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\auto-common\1.2\auto-common-1.2.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.12.0\checker-qual-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.11.0\error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.3\j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec\4.1.78.Final\netty-codec-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler\4.1.78.Final\netty-handler-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-epoll\4.1.78.Final\netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-kqueue\4.1.78.Final\netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver\4.1.78.Final\netty-resolver-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-exporter-logging\1.15.0\opentelemetry-exporter-logging-1.15.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-metrics\1.15.0\opentelemetry-sdk-metrics-1.15.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-logs\1.15.0-alpha\opentelemetry-sdk-logs-1.15.0-alpha.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\asynchttpclient\async-http-client-netty-utils\2.12.3\async-http-client-netty-utils-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-socks\4.1.60.Final\netty-codec-socks-4.1.60.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler-proxy\4.1.60.Final\netty-handler-proxy-4.1.60.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-epoll\4.1.60.Final\netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.60.Final-linux-x86_64.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-kqueue\4.1.60.Final\netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.60.Final-osx-x86_64.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.3\reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\netty\netty-reactive-streams\2.0.4\netty-reactive-streams-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar
-p C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport\4.1.78.Final\netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\4.3.0\selenium-remote-driver-4.3.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-classes-kqueue\4.1.78.Final\netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-javafx\12.2.0\ikonli-javafx-12.2.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\4.3.0\selenium-api-4.3.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-http\4.3.0\selenium-http-4.3.0.jar;F:\PROJELER\instagramtool\target\classes;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-trace\1.15.0\opentelemetry-sdk-trace-1.15.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk\1.15.0\opentelemetry-sdk-1.15.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-unix-common\4.1.78.Final\netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\15.0.1\javafx-controls-15.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-buffer\4.1.78.Final\netty-buffer-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\ous\jtoml\2.0.0\jtoml-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.10\byte-buddy-1.12.10.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-common\4.1.78.Final\netty-common-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chromium-driver\4.3.0\selenium-chromium-driver-4.3.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-common\1.15.0\opentelemetry-sdk-common-1.15.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\15.0.1\javafx-fxml-15.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-api\1.15.0\opentelemetry-api-1.15.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\15.0.1\javafx-base-15.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-json\4.3.0\selenium-json-4.3.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure\1.15.0-alpha\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-1.15.0-alpha.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-semconv\1.15.0-alpha\opentelemetry-semconv-1.15.0-alpha.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.82\jcommander-1.82.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\controlsfx\controlsfx\11.1.0\controlsfx-11.1.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-core\12.2.0\ikonli-core-12.2.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.78.Final\netty-codec-http-4.1.78.Final.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\4.3.0\selenium-chrome-driver-4.3.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\asynchttpclient\async-http-client\2.12.3\async-http-client-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi\1.15.0\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi-1.15.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\dev\failsafe\failsafe\3.2.4\failsafe-3.2.4.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\15.0.1\javafx-graphics-15.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-context\1.15.0\opentelemetry-context-1.15.0.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\31.1-jre\guava-31.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\izcie\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-classes-epoll\4.1.78.Final\netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.78.Final.jar
-m com.ege.instagramtool/com.ege.instagramtool.HelloApplication Haz 26, 2022 4:46:35 ÖS javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 18 by JavaFX
runtime of version 15.0.1 SLF4J: Failed to load class
"org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation
(NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See
http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
details. Starting ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.61
(0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819})
on port 59087 Only local connections are allowed. Please see
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for
suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started
successfully. Haz 26, 2022 4:46:36 ÖS
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
Detected upstream dialect: W3C Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)     at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)     at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
method  at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) Caused by:
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/F:/PROJELER/instagramtool/target/classes/com/ege/instagramtool/hello-view.fxml

    at
javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2677)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2517)    at
com.ege.instagramtool/com.ege.instagramtool.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:14)
    at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at
java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
Method)     at
javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)     at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)    at
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at
javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2673)
    ... 12 more Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpInfo: module
org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver does not declare `uses`   at
java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:591)  at
java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.checkCaller(ServiceLoader.java:577)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.<init>(ServiceLoader.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.load(ServiceLoader.java:1648)
    at
org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder.<init>(CdpVersionFinder.java:44)
    at
org.seleniumhq.selenium.chromium_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:118)
    at
org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
    at
org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:49)
    at
com.ege.instagramtool/com.ege.instagramtool.HelloController.initialize(HelloController.java:39)
    ... 23 more Exception running application
com.ege.instagramtool.HelloApplication

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Format the stack trace as code rather than quote and it will be easier to read.

Comment: According to `https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_library/`, it looks like you are using the wrong dependency.

Comment: try `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with the following maven dependency in IntelliJ:

```xml
<dependency>     
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>     
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>     
<version>4.4.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

I simply followed the answer from [Java 16 ChromeDriver WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type even after following all the necessary steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474878/java-16-chromedriver-webdriver-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-even-after-following) and deleted my `module-info.java` file and it worked.